# SQL throwing "invalid identifier" error

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number, where-in

The following query is throwing the, `"00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"` error on the alias 'RANKING'. Can't figure out why this doesn't work. If I eliminate the 'WHERE' clause, it produces the correct result.

```
SELECT RELEASE_NAME, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) AS RANKING
 FROM(
   SELECT RELEASE_NAME, MIN(START_DATE) AS START_DATE FROM RM_TASK_STATUS_VIEW
        WHERE RELEASE_NAME LIKE '%AU%' AND START_DATE IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY RELEASE_NAME
        ORDER BY START_DATE
  ) 
WHERE RANKING IN (3,4);
```

Comment: You referred the alias name in `SELECT` as `WHERE` condition as well! You need to use the entire expression again in `WHERE` condition or subquery it again. As alias names cannot be referred in `WHERE` clause but only in `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Actually, you can't use row_number() in a where clause. You will get SQL Error: ORA-30483.

Answer (score 1):

Make a derived table of your query, and put the where clause at the end.

```
select * from 
(your query, minus the where clause, goes here) temp
WHERE RANKING IN (3,4);
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Although @Stripthesoul explanation will help me remember why - I think it is important to understand the underlying problem than just fixing the syntax (although sometimes you really just need the syntax).